# How to get google cloud storage public url out from firebase storage download url?

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

In our system the users upload their images using our mobile app to firebase storage which is a wrapper over google cloud storage bucket, the mobile app is using [this library](https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage) to do the upload, and then use the `getDownloadUrl` method (described in the link) to generate a download link like the following:

[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{BUCKET_NAME}/o/{PARENT_FOLDER}/{IMAGE_NAME}?alt=media&token={UUID}](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%7BBUCKET_NAME%7D/o/%7BPARENT_FOLDER%7D/%7BIMAGE_NAME%7D?alt=media&token=%7BUUID%7D)

Then it sends the URL to our BE to store the link.

The download time for firebase storage links is much longer than downloading the exact same image directly from google cloud storage link which is simply could be generated from the following link template
[https://storage.googleapis.com/{BUCKET_NAME}/{PARENT_FOLDER}/{IMAGE_NAME}](https://storage.googleapis.com/%7BBUCKET_NAME%7D/%7BPARENT_FOLDER%7D/%7BIMAGE_NAME%7D).

As GCP link is faster (according to our own benchmark), then we need a way to map firebase link into its counter part in GCP storage to improve the download performance.

The solution described above to do the mapping is right for any image that is publicly available in the GCP bucket, however, if the image is not publicly available then it could be accessed using firebase link (maybe because it has the token in the link), but we can not access it using the GCP link and it gives the following error:

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access denied.</Message>
   <Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details>
</Error>
```

My question is:
How can we access the image from GCP storage link, even if it is not public, given that we can not make all images public due to security reasons?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: if a file is not marked public in the Storage bucket, it cannot be access through a `storage.googleapis.com` link.

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong, from what I understood you want to give access to a image in a GCS bucket which is not public, is that correct?

Comment: @LluísMuñoz Yes I want to keep my image not public however let the CDN to access it, so that I can get the cache benefits and make sure of the security as well, do you think that is possible?

Comment: @Motaz It's not an ideal solution but you can use [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl), the main drawback is that the longest expiration value is 604800 seconds (7days), as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#:~:text=The%20longest%20expiration%20value%20is%20604800%20seconds%20(7%20days).)  

Please note that this limitation didn't happen in V2 Signing Process but that is legacy now, and using V4 Signing Process is recommended.